# How to write a unit test for a React.js project?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a web-based e-commerce site. Now I need to perform unit testing. Are there any tools required for unit testing?

Comment: If you're using create-react-app then it will come with testing already configured. It uses jest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of testing frameworks and libraries for this.

The ones I use are [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/)

There is a curve for the setup but if you are using `create-react-app` it's already done.

As for the question 'how'. It's dependent of the code because some components just render props and the testing itself is just checking that the props are rendered a certain way.

Some other components have data fetching, hooks and dependencies that need mocking. Until you learn the quirks of both libraries I would advise testing simpler components first. I leave one example

```
========== index.js ============
import React from 'react'

export default function MyComponent(){
 return <div>test</div>
}

=========== index.test.js =============
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import MyComponent from '.'

test("should render 'test'", () => {
  render(<MyComponent />)
  expect(screen.queryByText("test")).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```